# How to match only specified xml tag of xml file uploaded

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, database, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to upload xml files which specifies certain tag only. Otherwise, the uploading fails. I am using MVC 5 framework application

Here is what I have done. For my controller,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase xmlFile)
{
     if (xmlFile.ContentType.Equals("application/xml") || xmlFile.ContentType.Equals("text/xml"))
     {
          var xmlPath = Server.MapPath("~/XML/" + xmlFile.FileName);
          xmlFile.SaveAs(xmlPath);
          XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);

          List<Product> productList = xDoc.Descendants("product").Select(product => new Product
          {
               Id = Convert.ToInt32(product.Element("id").Value),
               Name = product.Element("name").Value,
               Price = Convert.ToDecimal(product.Element("price").Value),
               Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(product.Element("quantity").Value)
          }).ToList();

          using (testXMLEnt db = new testXMLEnt())
          {
               foreach (var i in productList)
               {
                    var v = db.Products.Where(a => a.Id.Equals(i.Id)).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (v != null)
                    {
                        v.Id = i.Id;
                        v.Name = i.Name;
                        v.Price = i.Price;
                        v.Quantity = i.Quantity;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        db.Products.Add(i);
                    }
                        db.SaveChanges();
               }
          }
                ViewBag.Success = "File uploaded successfully..";
      }
      else
      {
          ViewBag.Error = "Invalid file(Upload xml file only)";
      }
      return View();
}
```

These are two different of xml file which will be uploaded.
File1.xml

```
<customers>  
  <customer>  
    <id>1</id>  
    <name>Mobele Phone</name>  
    <price>12000</price>  
    <quantity>2</quantity>  
  </customer> 
</customers>
```

File2.xml

```
<products>  
  <product>  
    <id>1</id>  
    <name>Mobele Phone</name>  
    <price>12000</price>  
    <quantity>2</quantity>  
  </product>
```

The difference between File1 and File2 is `<customer>` and `<product>`.
How can I specify the successfully file uploaded will only be the file with  tag. otherwise, the upload fails.

Comment: Do is in two steps.  First:  List<XElement> products = Doc.Descendants("product").ToList()  If you get a list of zero rows then skip the file.

Comment: How do I write that in syntax? @jdweng